# Making table rows but not table headers clickable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am using

```
$('#mytable tr').click(function() {
    blah blah
});
```

This makes all rows, including the headers clickable. How can I exclude the headers or `<th>`'s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate you header and body using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, and change your selector to `"#mytable tbody tr"`

HTML will look something like this

```
<table> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
         ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            ...
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, assuming you've marked your `table` up accurately, is to use:

```
 $('#mytable tbody tr').click(function() {
     blah blah
 });
```

Failing that:

```
 $('#mytable tr').filter(
     function(){
         return $(this).find('td').length;
     }).click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('clicked');
 });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zJCGN/).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them with the `not` function:

```
$('#mytable tr').not('th').click(function() {
   blah blah
});
```

Or:

```
$('#mytable tr:not(th)').click(function() {
   blah blah
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery delegate

```
$("#mytable").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  //Do something
});
```

this should work