# Make table row clickable but not headers only with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to archive the same as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003715/making-table-rows-but-not-table-headers-clickable-in-jquery) using **only javascript and no jquery**? The goal is to detect clicks on individual rows, while ignoring clicks on the header.

My approach so far:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var table = document.getElementById("table01");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log('clicked')
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="table01">
  <thead class="thead-green">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What mean by header.

Comment: Any fiddle would be useful to illustrate your issue.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq The table header - the rows listed under <thead>

Comment: @AUBSieGUL Hmm ... Actually, you don't have to remove `th` elements from `tr`s in `tbody`, they are valid. That just makes a a one more step to the single `tbody` listener, i.e. if there are `th`s, you've to check the tag name on evey click, and return early, if `th` was clicked.

Comment: @AUBSieGUL Just for reference, I made you [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17vsbp8L/). It shows how you can use event delegation and objects to create a handler for multiple tables on the same page. You can add more properties and methods to the object as you need, ex. a `addRow` method might be useful, or `removeRow` as well.

Comment: @Teemu I checked it out thank you! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid attaching event listeners to each individual rows, for two reasons:

1. If the table is too long, the large number of event listeners will
   hurt performance
2. If the table content is dynamic, newly added rows
   will require new listeners to be added.

Instead, you can attach an event listener on the entire table and check if the click target is inside the `tbody`. (this is also known as the [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) pattern in JavaScript)

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table01");
table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest('tbody')) {
    console.log(e.target.closest('tr')); // emit the row you just clicked;
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="table01">
  <thead class="thead-green">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And even simpler than that, you can attach event listener onto the `tbody`. This way you can guarantee all clicks come from rows in the table body.

```js
var tableBody = document.getElementById("table01").querySelector('tbody');
tableBody.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest('tr')) {
    console.log(e.target.closest('tr')); // emit the row you just clicked;
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="table01">
  <thead class="thead-green">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">A</th>
      <th scope="col">B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Meanwhile, please consider the accessibility of your desired behavior. How will a keyboard user trigger this kind of click? How will a screen reader user know the rows are actually "clickable"?

Comment: This is the best answer so far, only that the goal was to not trigger the event on `th` elements, which your solution doesn't implement (easy to add, though).

Comment: Somehow document.getElementById('table01'); always returnes NULL. If I add an Eventlistener to the document first it works fine.

Comment: Did the same, then check for non-clickables I guess.
`if (!!(<HTMLElement>e.target)?.closest('td')?.querySelectorAll('p-dropdown').length) { // dropdown exists inside this td`

Answer (score 2):

Just made little modification to Your `javascript`. See provided code :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var table = document.getElementById("table01");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      alert('clicked');
    })
  }
});
```

You'll see that modification is made in Your `var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");`. By this way You'll get only rows from `tbody`, not entire table (`thead` and `tfoot`) using pure `javascript` and avoid `querySelector` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#table01>tbody>tr").forEach(function(tr){tr.addEventListener....};
```

">" stands for the direct children.

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the headers in a variable and check if any of those are the descendants of each row

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       var hasHeader = false;
        for (j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                 if(rows[i].contains(headers[j])) {
                        hasHeader = true;
                        break;
                } 
      } 
        if(!hasHeaders) {
             rows[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              console.log('clicked')
            })
      } 
}
```